# Two-Way anova assumptions not fulfilled

Tags: r, anova, two-way, levenes-test, shapiro-wilk-test

My task is to determine whether two different categorical variables (residence location (city/rural) & residence size (small/medium/large))  have a connection on one numeric variable (residence size (m^2)). Here's how I started with R studio:

1. determine mean, median and standard deviation
2. Shapiro-Wilk tests of normal distribution and Tukey boxplot with subsets for city and rural
3. Levene test for equal variances
4. Two-way anova
5. Multiple comparisons with TukeyHSD

I stumbled across a problem. Two-way ANOVA assumptions require that the data follows normal distribution and has equal variances. My Shapiro-Wilk tests show that only in rural small residences the normal distribution assumption is true. Also Levene's test shows that variances are not equal for area(m^2)~size(small/medium/large)*location(city/rural).

I have thought about data transformation, but cannot figure out a way to perform that. Am I correct that this is necessary in this situation? How would one perform a transformation in R Studio on positively skewed data?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sure there are several posts on this site that cover this issue in sufficient detail. ... It is not the case that anova requires the ***data*** to be normally distributed.  If you want to assess the conditional normality of the data, you will probably want to look at the residuals from the analysis, not the observed data per se. ... Also, it's really not a good idea to use e.g. Shapiro-Wilk or Levene's test in this way. One problem is that they are likely to return significant results for large data sets even for small deviations from e.g. a normal distribution.  (Con't).

Comment: (Con't).  Another problem is that this makes one hypothesis test contingent on the result of another hypothesis test, which makes the p-value of the second test difficult to interpret.   Finally, anova is somewhat robust to deviations for normality and homoscedasticity, and there are methods to deal with the heteroscedasticity.  ... You are better off using plots and an understanding of the data you are studying to determine if anova is an appropriate approach or not.

Comment: It may appropriate to use a transformation for right skewed data (such as square root, cube root, or log).  There's also Tukey's ladder of powers, and Box-Cox transformation.  ...  However, using Gamma regression may be appropriate for a variable like Residence Size.  This is relatively straightforward to conduct in R, using *glm()*, *car::Anova(*), and the *emmeans* package.